# Pagination with tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The html below gets dynamically created so I don't have access to change the html:

```
<div class="entryFooter">Last Edited by Anonymous at 03/11/2011 15:36 </div>
<br>
<table border="0"> </table>
<br>
<table border="0"> </table>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
```

I am trying to create pagination through the tables as described in http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-pagination but am not successful. I've tried

```
$(function(){
itemsPerPage = 3;
paginatorStyle = 2;
paginatorPosition = 'botton';
enableGoToPage = true;
$("table").pagination();
});
```

but the pagination controls get added to every table. Is it possible I could paginate through the tables when they don't have id's or classes.

Thanks

Comment: There is a typo in your `paginatorPosition`. Should be `bottom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but, You could use something like the '[eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)' to refer to your tables by the position they appear on you page -

```
$("table:eq(0)").pagination(); //only applies to first table on page
```